# What determines the Google bio frame upon search relevance/subjects?

Tags: google-search

When you search for, say, a major public figure or celebrity, Google presents a little bio frame/bar on the right of the screen with info it pulls from various sources, including images and such of said person. I was wondering a few things about how Google pulls his info and decides on the bio:

1. Is this all automated? That is, can anyone with enough search data have this frame added? Or does it manually get approved by a human and thus must be submitted/collected upon?
2. Is there a specific database or set of knowledge that Google pulls/looks for or algorithmically determines before this frame is created for a certain business, public figure or small celebrity?

I ask because I've seen these frames appear for people who have no Wikipedias nor other generally "notable" or "noteworthy" records -- for example, small/minor YouTubers have these frames appear despite not having news articles about them much or other info.

What really decides this bio frame if it's not Wikipedia noteworthiness or the like?

This is what I'm referring to in case someone doesn't know what I mean:

[image]

If anyone doesn't notice, she doesn't have a Wikipedia linked nor much relevance overall, but she has a Google frame. Likewise, there are people with Wikipedia articles who don't have this frame appear on search when you Google them -- so that's why I question how this works.

Answer (score 1):

In the case used to describe the situation, actually there is a Wikipedia page about the person shown

1. Click on the photograph
2. Then click "Visit"
3. It will take you to https://uz.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexis_Love. On that page there is biographic data.

When data is taken from a single online source, a link is included on the card. In cases where the source isn't disclosed, only Google knows how do they took the information. Please note that users could propose changes to data by clicking on the Feedback link below the card.

It's worth to say that the feature discussed was named "Knowledge Graph". On the past where a help article on the official Help Center and other resources describing it in English but they were removed. The Spanish version of Google Inside is still available https://www.google.com/intl/es-419/insidesearch/features/search/knowledge.html

References

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_Graph